# Generating 3D array from 2D array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a music game where I have to generate a 3D array from a basic 2D array. The plan was to copy and paste the 2D array 4 times into the 3D array before modifying it, as shown:

```
var note3base = [
["C", "E", "G"],
["C#", "E#", "G#"],
["Db", "F", "Ab"],
["D", "F#", "A"],
["Eb", "G", "Bb"],
["E", "G#", "B"],
["F", "A", "C"],
["F#", "A#", "C#"],
["Gb", "Bb", "Db"],
["G", "B", "D"],
["Ab", "C", "Eb"],
["A", "C#", "E"],
["Bb", "D", "F"],
["B", "D#", "F#"],
["Cb", "Eb", "Gb"]
];

var note3 = new Array(4);

for (h=0;h<note3.length;h++){
note3[h] = note3base;
} //creates 4 copies of note3base in a 3d-array to be modified

for (i=0;i<note3[0].length;i++){
note3[1][i][1] = flat(note3[1][i][1]); //minor
note3[2][i][1] = flat(note3[2][i][1]);
note3[2][i][2] = flat(note3[2][i][2]); //dim
note3[3][i][2] = sharp(note3[3][i][2]); //aug
} //how did everything become the same?
```

The problem now seems to be that the `for` loop seems to apply the method to every single array (0 through 3).

The desired output for note3[0][1] would be C E G, note3[1][1] would be C Eb G, note[2][1] would be C Eb Gb, note[3][1] would be C E G#.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

I've included the (working) sharp and flat methods below for reference:

```
function sharp(note){
  var newnote;
  if (note.charAt(1) == "#"){
    newnote = note.replace("#", "x");
  } else if (note.charAt(1) == "b"){
    newnote = note.replace("b", "");
  } else {
    newnote = note + "#";
  }
  return newnote;
 }

function flat(note){
   var newnote;
   if (note.charAt(1) == "#"){
     newnote = note.replace("#", "");
   } else {
     newnote = note + "b";
   }
   return newnote;
}
```

Comment: Note that your `flat()` function needs an `else if` case like your `sharp()` function, to cover double-flats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you assign a variable equal to an array like this:

```
someVar = someArray;
```

...it doesn't make a copy of the array, it creates a second reference to the *same* array. (This applies to all objects, and arrays are a type of object.) So after your loop, where you've said:

```
for (h=0;h<note3.length;h++){
  note3[h] = note3base;
```

...all of the elements in `note3` refer to the same underlying array.

To make an actual copy, you can manually copy all of the elements across using a loop, or you can use the [`.slice()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to make a copy for you:

```
for (h=0;h<note3.length;h++){
  note3[h] = note3base.slice();
}
```

But that will only solve half of the problem, because `note3base` itself contains references to other arrays, and `.slice()` will just copy these references. That is, although `note3[0]` and `note3[1]` (and 2 and 3) will refer to different arrays, `note3[0][0]` and `note3[1][0]` and `note3[2][0]` and `note3[3][0]` will refer to the same `["C", "E", "G"]` array. (And so forth.)

You need what's called a "deep copy". You could do it with a nested loop:

```
for (h=0;h<note3.length;h++){
  // create this element as a new empty array:
  note3[h] = [];
  // for each 3-note array in note3base
  for (var k = 0; k < note3base.length; k++) {
    // make a copy with slice
    note3[h][k] = note3base[k].slice();
  }
}
```

Having said all that, I think an easier way to do the whole thing would be instead of having a `note3base` *variable* that refers to an array, make it a function that returns a new array:

```
function makeNote3Array() {
  return [
    ["C", "E", "G"],
    ["C#", "E#", "G#"],
    ["Db", "F", "Ab"],
    ["D", "F#", "A"],
    ["Eb", "G", "Bb"],
    ["E", "G#", "B"],
    ["F", "A", "C"],
    ["F#", "A#", "C#"],
    ["Gb", "Bb", "Db"],
    ["G", "B", "D"],
    ["Ab", "C", "Eb"],
    ["A", "C#", "E"],
    ["Bb", "D", "F"],
    ["B", "D#", "F#"],
    ["Cb", "Eb", "Gb"]
  ];
}
```

Because the function uses an array literal it will create a brand new array of arrays every time it is called. So then you can do the following, with no need for `.slice()` or nested loops:

```
var note3 = new Array(4);
for (h=0;h<note3.length;h++){
  note3[h] = makeNote3Array();
}
```

Comment: that's a really clear explanation! with an even better solution to boot! thanks alot!

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**, do this:

```
for (h=0;h<note3.length;h++){
  note3[h] = note3base.slice(0);
}
```

**Explanation:**

The problem is coming from the difference between passing something'by value' and 'by reference' in Javascript.

When you assign a primitive value to a variable, like `a = "string";`, and then assign that to another variable, like `b = a;`, the value is passed to `b` 'by-value': its *value* is assigned to `b`, but `b` references a different part of memory. There are now two "string" values in the memory, one for `a`, and one for `b`.

```
a = "string";
b = a;
a = "gnirts";
console.log(b);   // "string"
```

This is not how it works for non-primitive types, such as arrays. Here the value is passed to `b` 'by reference', meaning that there is still only one [1, 2, 3] array in the memory, and both `a` and `b` are pointing at it. This means that is you change an element in `a`, it will change for `b` as well, because they reference the same array in memory. So you get this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3];
b = a;
a[0] = "hello";
console.log(b);   // ["hello", 2, 3]
```

`b[0]` has changed because it references the same location in memory as `a[0]`. To get around this problem, we need to explicitly make a copy of note3base when passing it to another variable, rather than just passing it by reference. We can do this with `note3base.slice(0)` as above.

Edit: read more [here](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass)